# How to Download Through POST using wget

Tags: ubuntu, wget

If I have a URL similar to this: http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834

How do I download the file using wget? Everytime I try I always end up downloading the php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php` file you downloaded with `wget` is actually a `zip` file with `php` extensions. Rename the file extension and you'll be able to extract the contents normally.

`wget` saves the file with the same name as the filename in the URL by default. To set the output name, see @bfhd`s comment.

For a case where you need to POST authentication information, you can do the following, which is extracted from [StackOverflow: How to use wget post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-use-wget-post-data/1432161#1432161)

```
# Log in to the server.  This can be done only once.                   
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
     --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
     http://server.com/auth.php

# Now grab the page or pages we care about.
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     -p http://server.com/interesting/article.php
```

Comment: You can also do "wget -O zipfile.zip http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834" which will rename the file for you.